# Why is there a separate queue at immigration for first time visitors and one for repeat?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, us-visa-waiver-program, ewr

My brother just landed in the USA at Newark and told there were separate queues -- one for those who have entered the USA within the last two years on ESTA and the other for first time visitors. Why is this separation in place?

Comment: Don't they collect fingerprints on your first visit? Possibly the airport only equipped certain booths with the scanners. I don't recall seeing such a distinction when I landed at DEN a few months back, so possibly it's a particular airport...

Comment: Which airport? AFAIK this distinction is being phased out, and I was under the impression that it already had been.

Comment: Maybe https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/115955/1362 ? First-timers have to see an officer to have their identities checked and be fingerprinted; others can have their identities verified with their fingerprints at an automatic kiosk.

Comment: The airport is EWR, edited.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Varies from airport to airport

Comment: Just landed at LAX (from a Virgin Atlantic flight) on 39 March 2019. There was one line. When they released a group into the APC area, some people bypassed them to join a 2nd line. Once done with APC, I joined the 2nd line. When I reached the end of that line, upon brandishing my receipt, I was sent directly to baggage claim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would be due to the APC kiosks of course, which, at certain airports, are only available to VWP nationals with a previous entry (i.e. having been fingerprinted and photographed). In addition, depending on the airport, it might be a requirement that a previous entry has been made on the currently held passport.

Comment: What's the point of fingerprinting if they don't it on every entry...

Comment: @chx They do fingerprint on every entry, the point is that they can't compare you against your last prints if you've never been to the US before.

Comment: @jpatokal I think chx is confused about it because he as a Canadian is exempt from being fingerprinted. BTW, at certain airports first-time VWP visitors can now use the kiosks